# Bookmark-based hg workflow for open-source project

Tags: mercurial, workflow

In the SCons project, we use mercurial with [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/scons/scons).  We'd like to have several ongoing features under development by different people (perhaps multiple people working on a single feature, or a single person working on multiple features).  We've tried named branches, but they don't really work well for feature development in mercurial.  We'd like something like the git branch system, where branches are lighter weight and not as permanent, but still shared.  Other than separate repos per feature, which I don't think we're ready for (too radical), the community seems to say bookmarks are the way to go here; do all development on the default branch, but with bookmarks for each head (feature).

First question: is that a reasonable workflow?  Are any other projects working that way?

Second question: having tried this a little, one thing that's confusing is when you do `hg update default` it's semi-random which head you get; it depends on which one was updated last.  You really have to do `hg update featureX` or `hg update featureY` or else (a) you land on a random head, and (b) no bookmarks are "activated" so you end up not moving that bookmark forward. This seems like a recipe for failure.  I assume I'm missing something.  Anyone who's using a workflow like this: how do you get past this?

Comment: May I ask what doesn't really work well with named branches? Bear in mind that I'm not saying you're wrong, I just want to know what particular reasons or behavior you observed that doesn't work for you, might give us some information that might help us help you.

Answer (score -2):

> named branches ... they don't really work well for feature development in mercurial

RLLY?! I use NB all time, long time and can't find any problems. That I'm doing wrong?

Forget (*if* it happened) one time `--new-branch` on push, get reject and repeat correct command is **minimal cost** for all named branches usefulnesses

> the community seems to say bookmarks are the way to go here

1. Community must have no voice in such cases
2. Community is always a **set of idiots**, even if **each** individually **is genius**
3. It must be personal responsibility of Project Lead

> is that a reasonable workflow?

At least Steve Losh in "A Guide to Branching in Mercurial" [note](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-bookmarks) it

> Are any other projects working that way?

Why not? Bookmark-style has some advantages in some eyes (which are also disadvantages at the same time in another)

> when you do `hg update default` it's semi-random which head you get

Just **totally forget** `hg up` with branch-name or parameter-less and **always** update with needed bookmark-name. If your team consists of young girls with short memory, they can build crutches in form of one or two [aliases](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias).

In not hopeless case it can be something like

```
bup = update ACTIVE-BOOKMARK-NAME
```

there `ACTIVE-BOOKMARK-NAME` is a placeholder for assigned to user bookmark (and it's user's area of responsibility to edit .hgrc and replace bookmark on changing task) and user have to `hg up` in order to update to bookmark and `hg up ANY` in order to use free-form update

For blondes and code-monkeys you can prepare set of two aliases, one of which overload default `hg up`: strictly not recommended

> **It is possible to create aliases with the same names as existing
>   commands, which will then override the original definitions. This is
>   almost always a bad idea!**

but possible, like, f.e.

```
update = update ACTIVE-BOOKMARK-NAME
pup = update $1
```

I.e with `hg up`|`hg update` without parameters user can update only to bookmark, for (rare) updating to any other changeset new command in form `hg pup CSET-ID` must be used

*Theoretically* (not tested), each coder can get own unique alias, which can be maintained and deployed into workplace in a centralized manner with [Projrc Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ProjrcExtension), using user-specific `include` directives for fetching only needed keys from central's repository `.hg/projrc`

Comment: This is not a helpful response, this is a rant.